# ElasticSearch Aggregation Group by order by sub terms field doc count

Tags: c#, sql, elasticsearch, nest

My mapping model:

// TypeLog: Error, Info, Warn

```
{
   "onef-sora": {
      "mappings": {
         "Log": {
            "properties": {

               "application": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
               "typeLog": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "application": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "application",
        "order" : { "_count" : "desc"},
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "typelogs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "typeLog",
            "order" : { "_term" : "asc"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want get top 5 application has most error, but term aggregation order support three key : _count, _term, _key. How do I order by typeLog doc_count in my query. Thanks !!!

Result I want:

```
 {
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 10000,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "application": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 5000,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "OneF0",
               "doc_count": 1000,
               "typelogs": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "error",
                        "doc_count": 334
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "info",
                        "doc_count": 333
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "warn",
                        "doc_count": 333
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "OneF1",
               "doc_count": 1000,
               "typelogs": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "error",
                        "doc_count": 333
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "info",
                        "doc_count": 334
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "warn",
                        "doc_count": 333
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "OneF2",
               "doc_count": 1000,
               "typelogs": {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "error",
                        "doc_count": 332
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "info",
                        "doc_count": 333
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "warn",
                        "doc_count": 334
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply using `_count: desc` as well in your `typelogs` sub-aggregation?

Comment: meaningless, i has try. I want get top application has type = 'Error'

Comment: Not sure I understand, but what @juliendangers provided should work and he uses `_count: desc` as advised. You may just remove the `term` query, but it should work.

Comment: he just add filters query, i want get top  doc_count typeLog = error and group by typeLog(include Warn,Info)

Answer (score 1):

As you to get the top 5 applications with most errors, you can filter to keep only error logs in query (you could use a filter). Then you only need order you sub-term aggregation by descending count

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "typeLog": "Error"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "application": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "application",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "typelogs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "typeLog",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To keep all typeLogs, you may need to perform your query the other way

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "typelogs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "typeLog",
        "order": {
          "_count": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "application": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "application",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have 3 first level buckets, the the top 5 applications by type of log

Comment: i don't want filters, i want get total warn, info type

Comment: You're asking for the top 5 applications with the most logs, but the top application could have only info logs, so you won't be able to get the ones with most errors without filtering documents.

Btw, please edit your question to add that you want all typeLog ;)

Comment: if you do not filter, you could get the following result https://gist.github.com/juliendangers/b68cf017dbec275df5d1

Comment: i need  how to query elasticsearch return result i want, not use filter, because i need count another log type(warn,info,...)

Comment: ok, you may need to do it a different way : https://gist.github.com/juliendangers/be9c8255a28573e7c2b1
   You perform a term aggregation by typeLog, and then a sub-aggregation by application. That way you'll have 3 buckets, 'error, info, warn', and top 5 applications by typeLog.

Comment: you don't understand what i mean, i want group by application, group by typelog, then get top 5 application most error

Comment: but that it's not possible in a single query, that's what I'm trying to explain :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93344/discussion-between-juliendangers-and-giau-huynh).